# Convert string to datetime fails

Tags: c#, .net

I can't seem to find how to convert a string to a datetime. Here is what my date looks like: "23-nov-12".

I tried the following:

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("dd-MMM-yy", "23-nov-12", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and also

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("0:d-MMM-yy", "23-nov-12", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I always get the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: There are thousands of threads talking about the same exact issue!
Do more research!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your arguments are in the wrong order. The date goes first.

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("23-nov-12", "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You got the parameters backwards.
The input string goes first.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23-nov-12", "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code Works...

```
  string dt = "23-nov-12";
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(dt));
```

It produces 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM as output

Try It!

Comment: Just use the .ToString(...) and format it the way you like. However never try using it without checking if the parse was a success

Comment: so it works and format it whatever you want as @JeremyK said. And ToDateTime uses your timezone.

Comment: DateTime cDt = DateTime.ParseExact("23-nov-12", "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(cDt); //Produces 11/23/2012 12:00:00 AM just like @SLaks suggested...